# Kivy on android no internet

Tags: android, websocket, kivy, buildozer

I build the application with kivy. The app connects to server with websocket-client library. It works fine on PC and even on Android phone but only if WiFi connection is established. If I disable WiFi and keep just mobile data the app doesn't work. Doesn't return any error, just doesn't got any callbacks. I have included INTERNET permission when building with buildozer.

Is there maybe some other permission for mobile data or what?

Thanks for any clue.

Edit:
I do some additional tests and got interesting results:
My App use 8080 port.

```
Connection port 8080 from phone over WiFi is OK. 
Connection port 8080 from phone over mobile data FAIL.
 
Connection port 8081 from phone over WiFi is OK. 
Connection port 8081 from phone over mobile data OK
```

So seems that somewhere from my phone-MobiledataProvider-MyServer port 8080 is blocked. But from my house WiFi-InternetProvider-MyServer the port 8080 is open.

Seems that this is not Kivy/Buildozer issue but mobile data provider.